# Find the PMF of guessing password correctly

Tags: probability, statistics

> Question: Suppose your old (but forgotten) computer password is set to a $2$-bit binary string. Let $X$ be the number of attempts that you take until you guess the password correctly. Note that any unsuccessful guess will obviously not be included in future attempts. Assuming each guess is random,derive the probability mass function of $X.$

I understand that the problem should be solved using geometric distribution.

However, in this case, I do not the probability of guessing password wrongly. 
Let $p$ be the required probability. 
Then for each natural number $k$, the PMF is 
$$P(X=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p.$$
But I have trouble finding $p$.
Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any unsuccessful guess won't be repeated, we have to consider the $4!$ permutations of the $2^2=4$ possible attempts at the password. The correct password will be the first attempt in the permutation in $3!=6$ cases, the second in another $6$ etc. So the PMF is discrete uniform, with$$P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(X=3)=P(X=4)=\frac14.$$

Comment: Why is it $4!$ ?

Comment: @Idonknow There are $4$ possible passwords. Sorry; I know it looked like I said there were $2$, because I'd accidentally typed `2%^2=4` instead of `2^2=4`.

Comment: Why are there 4 possible passwords?

Comment: @Idonknow Because that's the number of $2$-bit strings.